# How To Convert Datable To Html Table?

Tags: asp.net, datatable

for my web part,i need to show some data of data table.now,i m developing in asp.net with c#.
how i convert to html table from data table?And also,i don't need to show some column
such as ItemID.my data table will be like this.

ItemID     ItemName     Qty     Price     Unit     Amount

I-0001     ItemOne       10      100        Box           1000
I-0002     ItemTwo       20      200        Card   4000
I-0003     ItemThree    30      300        Tab           9000

itemID column is not need to show.i want only itemname,qty,price,unit,amount columns.
please give me right way.

regards

chong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  If you just want to use the `DataGrid` control, [here's a pretty comprehensive look](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135207/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040502-1.aspx) at that control.

Answer (score 3):

aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Items" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ItemID</th>
                <th>ItemName</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("ItemID")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("ItemName")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Qty")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Price")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Unit")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Amount")%></td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.cs file

```
Items.DataSource = DateTableID;
Items.DataBind();
```